# Django geting error when loading static files?

Tags: python, django

I have the code below to load static files, but I keep getting a `TemplateSyntaxError`. Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}
<img class="logo" alt="Test Pic" src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}" width="110" height="70">
{% block main %}
{% endblock %}
```

Settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
STATIC_URL = '/public/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "public")
```

URLS:

```
urlpatterns = [

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Error I get:

```
Invalid block tag on ...: 'static', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Comment: Try to remove {% load staticfiles %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed the issue was reinstalling Django.

Answer (score 0):

Just use {% load static %} on the top since it is recommended in newer versions of Django. I think using staticfiles and static at the same time creates a confusion.

Comment: Tried it, same result.

Comment: Can you add settings.py TEMPLATES section